# How can i give specific commands to programs via terminal Linux?

Tags: python, c, linux, bash, shell

I'm seeking for a way to automatize the configuration of some tasks i do, but, i am having some trouble to give the order to the programs from the terminal.

I have actually to give, every time i try to configure some Routers, the same commands always and always, but, i'm looking for a way to create a Shell Script to do it for me. The problem, is. I must access a server with terminal to do that,so i can't give the commands as i always do, with terminal. I need a way to insert the commands inside the terminal.

This is the terminal i'm wanting to automatize
[image]

As you can see, i ways have to do the same commands, that would be pretty better, if the Shell Script, itself, did it for me.

Last but no least, there is a sample of what i tried to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
telnet 192.168.255.2 & < enable; show port epon 1/1 registered-link;
show port epon 1/2 registered-link; show port epon 1/3 registered-link;
show port epon 1/4 registered-link; show port epon 2/1 registered-link; 
show port epon 2/2 registered-link; show port epon 2/3 registered-link; 
show port epon 2/4 registered-link; show port epon 3/1 registered-link; 
show port epon 3/2 registered-link; show port epon 3/3 registered-link;
show port epon 3/4 registered-link; show port epon 4/1 registered-link;
show port epon 4/2 registered-link; show port epon 4/3 registered-link;
show port epon 4/4 registered-link;
```

"telnet 192.168.255.2" is the server and the oders, are the commands it must do.

Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Do some research about *pipes* and *heredoc*.

Comment: There are people using telnet in 2017? Looking forward to hearing about the data breach on reddit.

Comment: You can write a shell script containing an expect script as an heredoc.

Comment: Hahahahaha welcome to Brasil...

Comment: ansible might be a worthy replacement to raw shell scripting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabric is your friend, designed exactly for that kind of task. http://www.fabfile.org/

You may use Fabric3 if you prefer Python 3. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3

Comment: And, BTW, install ssh-server and remove or deactivate telnet from your remote server. SSH is safer, provides FTP-like service and has more client tools and libs.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to need [the `pexpect` module](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which is specifically designed for running commands on remote computers through teletype-like channels. It uses a pseudo-teletype device to present to the remote system pretty much as a standard user logging in to a shell. You can write scripts to scan for particular outputs, and it's often trivially easy using Python to generate the commands you want to run remotely.